# Open a new window with new sites in tabs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have a Chorme extension and I need to create a button that opens some Google searches. As google limits searches to 32 keywords, so I needed to create several links, for example:

```
https://www.google.com.br/search?q=test
https://www.google.com.br/search?q=test2
https://www.google.com.br/search?q=test3
```

When I click on the button I need it to open a new window (chrome.windows.create) with the first link. Already the second and third link open with tab, but within that same new window.

If I put everything in windows.create, everything opens in separate windows and that's not what I want. If I put 2 and 3 in the search (chrome.tabs.create), it will open 1 link in a new window and 2 links in 2 tabs, but from the active window, that's not what I want either. I want everything to open in a new window, with the rest of the links in tabs within this new window. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `chrome.tabs.create` method to open the first link in a new window, and set the "`active`" property to `true`. This will make the new tab the active tab in the new window. Then, you can use a loop to open the remaining links in new tabs within the same window by passing the window ID of the new window as the "`windowId`" property in the chrome.tabs.create method for the remaining links.

```js
chrome.windows.create({
    url: "https://www.google.com.br/search?q=test",
    focused: true
}, function(newWindow) {
    chrome.tabs.create({
        url: "https://www.google.com.br/search?q=test2",
        windowId: newWindow.id
    });
    chrome.tabs.create({
        url: "https://www.google.com.br/search?q=test3",
        windowId: newWindow.id
    });
});
```

You can use this script as a function, and call it when you click on the button.

Answer (score 0):

Worked perfectly. I tried to improve the code using array, now it opens too, it works fine, however the first tab of the new window is blank, the others load correctly. what am I doing wrong?

```
 chrome.windows.create({focused: true, }, function(win) {
     var links = [('https://www.google.com.br/search?q=' + 'inurl%3A' + estado + buscaalteracoes5 + dias ),
     ('https://www.google.com.br/search?q=' + 'inurl%3A' + estado + buscainterditado1 + dias ),
    ('https://www.google.com.br/search?q=' + 'site%3Afacebook.com+inurl%3Aposts+inanchor%3A' + estado +
 buscainterditado1 + dias ),
     ('https://www.google.com.br/search?q=' + 'site%3Afacebook.com+inurl%3Aposts+inanchor%3A' + estado +
buscapavimentacoes1 + dias ), ];
     for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
       array = links[i];
       chrome.tabs.create({ 
           url: array, 
           windowId: win.id,
           selected: true
       })
     } });
```

Comment: To fix you can remove the "selected" option, or set it to false for all tabs except the first one.